# Can´t use ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a button dinamically with javascript and I added the ng-click="callSomething()" , when i render it, it have the corresponding class, but when I press the button it doesn´t work, I created a Button directly in the frontend with the same function and it works

This works

```
<button ng-click="callSomething(1231)" id="somethingButton">Change</button>
```

This isn´t working

```
button = `<td><button ng-click="callSomething(${data[i].order_number})" class="btn btn-primary" >Change</button></td>`
```

Please your help

Comment: because that is not how angularjs works. Why are you building a string? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to buid a table with a button in it, i didn't find a way to include it, so I try that

Comment: can you show how you are building a table?

Comment: `let cuerpo_table = document.getElementById("tabla_integracion");
texto = `<tr>
         <td>${datos[i].numero_pedido}</td>
         <td>${datos[i].rut_cliente}</td>
         <td>${datos[i].razon_social}</td>
         ${td}
         ${button}
cuerpo_table.innerHTML = texto;`

Comment: Why are you using DOM with angular js? Do call the angular method it needs to go through its processing. There should be better way to do what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Just because I don't know how to add a button with an ng-click element to a table as you normally do with data